# what is the use of @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")

Tags: android

I encountered `@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")` in some code i was going through and could not find out any description of it online. I understand `@SuppressLint("NewApi")` is used to hide warnings when we write code that is higher than the minsdk mentioned in the manifest. But i am not able to figure out when "InlinedApi" should be used. Any ideas?

Comment: Hm, that's a good question, I was able to find this

`Note: Since XY requires Android 3.0 (API version 11) or later, setting your app's minSdkVersion to 10 or below generates an Android Lint warning in Eclipse with ADK. To turn off this warning, add the annotation @SuppressLint("InlinedApi") before the definition of XY` [here](http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html).

So it seems to do the same as "newApi", maybe it's a predecessor of some sort?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

By executing `lint --list` (the lint tool is located in your `sdk/tools` directory) you can see a list of the valid issue id's. You can find the explanation of `InlinedApi` there :

> "InlinedApi": Finds inlined fields that may or may not work on older
>   platforms

Comment: That was really helpful. I am still thinking of a practical situation that this is required to be used i.e any example of a field that would not work on older platforms?

Comment: I found mine at `~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/lint`, and here is a text file containing the output: https://gist.github.com/ben-xD/843d70148942186e4da107aa26e5e61c

Comment: It has been updated to `"InlinedApi": Using inlined constants on older versions`

Answer (score 7):

Here's an example from [a Google codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/exoplayer-intro/#2):

```
@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
private void hideSystemUi() {
    mPlayerView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
}
```

If you comment out the `@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")`, you get this lint warning:

> Field requires API level 19 (current min is 16): android.view.View#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY

So you're accessing a field that may not exist in the API of some of the devices that you've said you want to be able to run the device on. In that case, why is it just a lint warning instead of a fatal compile error?

The fuller description for the warning is nice and informative. You can see it in Android Studio if you press the "More" key combo (e.g. <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) when the lint message popup is open. You can also get it via lint on the command line, similar to what @stan0 said but in more detail:

```
lint --show InlinedApi
```

Here's the detailed explanation:

> InlinedApi
> ----------
> Summary: Using inlined constants on older versions
>
> Priority: 6 / 10
> Severity: Warning
> Category: Correctness
>
> This check scans through all the Android API field references in the
> application and flags certain constants, such as static final integers
> and Strings, which were introduced in later versions. These will
> actually be copied into the class files rather than being referenced,
> which means that the value is available even when running on older
> devices. **In some cases that's fine, and in other cases it can result
> in a runtime crash or incorrect behavior. It depends on the context,
> so consider the code carefully and decide whether it's safe and can be
> suppressed or whether the code needs to be guarded.** [emphasis added]
>
> If you really want to use this API and don't need to support older
> devices just set the minSdkVersion in your build.gradle or
> AndroidManifest.xml files. If your code is deliberately accessing
> newer APIs, and you have ensured (e.g. with conditional execution)
> that this code will only ever be called on a supported platform, then
> you can annotate your class or method with the @TargetApi annotation
> specifying the local minimum SDK to apply, such as @TargetApi(11),
> such that this check considers 11 rather than your manifest file's
> minimum SDK as the required API level.

[(source)](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tips/lint-checks)

Hopefully with that explanation, it's clear why this is not a fatal error (because the value of the constant gets copied into the class file instead of a reference), why it's still potentially dangerous, and when to suppress the warning. In the codelab example above, the author apparently decided that adding a flag that wouldn't be recognized on older devices was safe. Maybe he had information that unrecognized flags would be silently ignored, though I don't see that in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setSystemUiVisibility(int)).

Comment: @Jon Thanks for catching my bad link.

Comment: Is it possible to set it for a single line/statement, instead of for a function?

Comment: @androiddeveloper I haven't found a way.

Comment: OK thanks. I know that some do support it. Maybe it has a different name there

Answer (score 1):

I found this..
      @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
      Indicates that Lint should ignore the specified warnings for the annotated element.

```
  Exp:
  SuppressLint
  implements from Annotation Class.
  android.annotation.SuppressLint like this..

  Built-In Annotations
```

Java defines a set of annotations that are built into the language
Annotations applied to java code:
    @Override - Checks that the method is an override. Causes a compile error if the method is not found in one of the parent classes or implemented interfaces.
    @Deprecated - Marks the method as obsolete. Causes a compile warning if the method is used.
    @SuppressWarnings - Instructs the compiler to suppress the compile time warnings specified in the annotation parameters

```
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/annotation/Annotation.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/annotation/SuppressLint.html
```

Comment: This is general information about annotations, and those that suppress Lint warnings. But the question here is specifically about the `"InlinedApi"` Lint warning.